# Quasiperiodic flows

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, topological-groups

Let $T^n$ be the standard $n$-torus and $f:T^n\to K$ a surjective continuous mapping of $T^n$ onto a compact space. Let $g^t$ be a quasiperiodic action of the real line $R$ on $T^n$, i.e., $g^t(\varphi)=\varphi+\omega t$ where $\omega$ is a fixed vector with rationally independent components. Let also $G^t$ be a continuous action of $R$ on $K$. Suppose that $f\circ g^t=G^t$. Then $K$ is a torus of dimension no greater than $n$, and $G^t$ is quasiperiodic.

This is an easy theorem (well, easy modulo the Pontryagin duality needed to describe the compact subgroups of $T^n$), and I am sure that it is known in the literature. My question is: where is it present? I need a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a reference where this result is precisely stated, but under these hypotheses is rather straightforward to show that the flow $G^t$ is isometric, and a nice reference for the result "every isometric minimal flow is equivalent to an homogeneous abelian group flow" is Terry Tao's blog (see Proposition 1 in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/24/254a-lecture-6-isometric-systems-and-isometric-extensions/ )

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, Proposition 1 in this blog is Proposition 2.6.7 in the book Tao, Terence. Poincaré's legacies, pages from year two of a mathematical blog. Part I. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2009. x+293 pp. ISBN: 978-0-8218-4883-8 MR2523047